# How can I put a full width input next to my div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small problem with my css/html code,
I want to put full width input next to my div

My HTML :

```
<div class="leftdiv"> </div>
<input type="text" id="title-input" placeholder="nothing"></div>
```

And here is my css :

```
.leftdiv {
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 60px;
}
#title-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

I want to say that the leftdiv have to be a 60px x 60px, so I can't use bootstrap's row (or yes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.leftdiv {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 60px;
}
#title-input {
  flex: 1;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="leftdiv"></div>
  <input type="text" id="title-input" placeholder="nothing" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `</div>` tag that closes the div immediately after opening it. That is your only mistake.

So it looks like that:

```
<div class="leftdiv">
  <input type="text" id="title-input" placeholder="nothing">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsnhvyte/